ValidationSummary not displaying inside component
I have a dialog that has a Contact component.  I pass in a Contact object from the dialog as a parameter to the component.  The component maps the Contact properties to a ContactModel.  I have a ValidationSummary, but it doesn't display the messages.  I verified that the EditContext is getting the ValidationMessageStore errors.  After a bit of testing I have found that if you pass in any object, not just the model, then the ValidationSummary doesn't work.  I changed it to passing a contactId and that works, but now I'm getting the contact twice.
Here's what I have:
//[Parameter]
public Contact CurrentContact { get; set; } = new();

[Parameter]
public int ContactId { get; set; }

private EditContext _editContext;
private ValidationMessageStore? messageStore;

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    try
    {
        if (ContactId == 0)
            CurrentContact = new Contact();
        else
            CurrentContact = await HttpHelper.GetObject<Contact>(state, $"contacts/contact/{ContactId}");

        _editContext = new(_model);

        _model = UtilityMethods.MapTo<ContactModel>(CurrentContact);
        if (_model.ContactID == 0)
            _model.Active = true;

        _editContext = new(_model);
        _editContext.OnValidationRequested += OnValidationRequestedAsync;

        messageStore = new(_editContext);

        StateHasChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await DialogService.AlertAsync(e.Message, "Contact");
    }
}

This code works because I commented out the object parameter and just used an int.  So how do I get the ValidationSummary to work while passing in an object?
Thank you.
